# Cordova IOS vertical scroll is not working.

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am trying to build a HTML5 app by using Cordova. There is a table in my app you **can** scroll **horizontally** but **not** **vertically**. I build the app for android and it is working ok. But in IOS it is not working.

My question is for cordova IOS can you make a table that can scroll both vertically and horizontally?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider using [`iScroll`](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)